# Defining isometric functors?

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces, category-theory

Does such a thing exist? This would require a metric or distance between two objects of a generic category, but I haven't heard of this.

Thoughts: the required compositionality (transitivity) of a category means that the minimum distance between objects is a bit trivial: you can always short-cut. Perhaps one can define a less trivial notion of distance on the transitive reduction of a category, by which I mean:

For any category $C$ perform the following sequence,

1. take the preorder associated with $C$
2. construct a partial order on the quotient set of the equivalence, C / ~, the set of all equivalence classes of ~. (Let any two distinct members of the same equivalence class have zero distance from one another).
3. examine the minimum (undirected?) distance between any two objects on transitive reduction of this partial order.

(In graph theory, the transitive reduction of a directed graph D has the same reachability relation as D. Equivalently, D and its transitive reduction should have the same transitive closure as each other, and its transitive reduction should have as few edges as possible among all graphs with this property. )

### Application

Consider functors F, G from the category with two objects and one non-identity morphism
$X \xrightarrow{f} Y$
to the category with three objects
$X' \xrightarrow{f'} Y'\xrightarrow{g'} Z' $.

Let the functor F take $f$ to $f'$, and the functor G take $f$ to $g' \circ f'$. Both F and G are fully faithful but intuitively F is more "veridical" or "isometric". Fullness and faithfulness do not say it all.  It is also important to consider what the distance would be, had the target category had an additional (non-composite) arrow $X' \xrightarrow{q} Z'$, and G instead mapped $f$ to $q$.

Comment: There are categories enriched over metric spaces, if that's what you're looking for. These have functors that transform distance in a controlled way.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no notion of distance between two objects in an arbitrary category, though you’re incorrect that you can always shortcut in a category. (Consider the category $a\to b$, with only identity morphisms pictured.) Picking a transitive reduction gives a badly ill defined notion of distance, though in principle there’s nothing stopping you if such a reduction exists. There is a kind of enriched category that generalizes metric spaces, in which the hom-set is replaced with a real number and associativity is replaced with the triangle inequality.

Comment: What I meant by "you can always short-cut" is: $f: a -> b $ and $ g: b -> c$ implies $gf: a -> c$.

Comment: @JRC OK. Presumably you want the distance to be something like the *longest* sequence of morphisms leading from $a$ to $c$.

Comment: Thanks. I would need to think about this, but perhaps only the longest directed sequences that do not contain an End(X,X) for all X (to avoid getting trapped in infinite sequences around the identities, etc). Alternatively, perhaps if all arrows of a category could be generated - using composition - by a finite arrow set, then the shortest sequence of generators from X to Y may a candidate for the "distance" from X to Y.